# Stop recursion from bidirectional one to one mappings

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a UserProfile Object that contains a reference to a TwitchAccount Object via a one to one relationship as shown here:

TwitchAccount.java:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "twitchAccount")
private UserProfile profile;
```

UserProfile.java:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "twitchAccountId", referencedColumnName = "twitchAccountId")
private TwitchAccount twitchAccount;
```

When I do a GET request on a specific TwitchAccount object, there seems to be a recursion between the two as seen:

```
{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":{"id":8,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"profilePicUrl":null,"birthday":null,"steamId":null,"xblId":null,"psnId":null,"epicId":null,"discordId":null,"twitchAccount":{"id":1,"state":"525367bb-ca4c-4131-ac52-e29aafdb7dc1","code":null,"userProfile":
```

How can I stop this recursion from happening, and how can i make it so the twitch account doesn't even return the json associated from the user profile object (the twitch account object shouldn't be able to set or get the userprofile anyways)?

Comment: Could you post some code from the Service where you convert between Models to DTOs?

Comment: @ChristosK. i was just returning the models themselves. is that bad?

Comment: It depends, are there any data that a user shouldn't see, doesn't the account table have a password field? Are you using some kind of JsonIgnore annotation? Still it's a better practice to convert to a custom non-entity class before exposing to a REST controller. For the recursion now, could you post the whole entities of TwitchAcount and UserProfile?

Comment: Also, when you make that GET request to get a TwitchAccount, do you need to also get with it the user profile? You should make clear what exactly is your goal

Comment: @ChristosK.  do not want it to contain the user profile. i believe you gave me the solution: use a dto that doesn’t contain the profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just annotate the `profile` property with @JsonIgnore, like this,

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "twitchAccount")
private UserProfile profile;
```

But this is certainly not a good practice, because this way you keep exposing entities which is a mistake and also because you would probably have a problem when you would need to expose the UserProfile.

So, create DTOs for both entities and on their relevant Services create conversion methods and it's done, you are in control of what you set.

---

However, this problem could be a bit more serious and to be more exact it could be a problem with your database tables and the relation between profile and account, but since you are not posting the rest of the code, there is no way to tell.

Just make sure to clear up what profile-account relation you need, because 
you might have created a bidirectional relation during database design instead of a unidirectional which is what, I guess, you are trying to accomplish.